# C# How can I put all my on off bools in a matrix and how can I control several at the same time?

Tags: c#, matrix, 2d, matrix-multiplication

How can I put all my on-off-bools in a matrix; and how can I control several at the same time?

I have 27 x 27 LED lights. So I need a Matrix with [27,27] and a how to:
I can't change the LED code self because it have custom code. I only want to easily switch them on / off, so I can make arrows or smiles on led screen :-)

example control

```
matrix[LED1 , LED9 , LED52] = true

    bool LED1 = false;
    bool LED2 = false;
    bool LED3 = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to an array like this:

```
bool[][] leds = new bool[27][];

for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    leds[i] = new bool[27];
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
        leds[i][j] = false;
    }
}
```

Then you can access and change the values like this:

```
leds[0][5] = true; //first index is the row, second index is the column
```